# Intrusive smart pointer implementation

Tags: c++, homework, pointers, c++20

I have homework in college to implement intrusive smart pointers.

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <string_view>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct RefCount
{
    inline void IncrementRefCount() const noexcept
    {
        refCount.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

    inline void DecrementRefCount() const noexcept
    {
        refCount.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel);
    }

    [[nodiscard]] inline uint32_t getRefCount() const noexcept { return refCount; }

private:
    mutable std::atomic_uint32_t refCount = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Ref 
{
    Ref() = default;

    Ref(std::nullptr_t) noexcept
        : data(nullptr)
    {
    }

    Ref(T* instance) noexcept
        : data(instance)
    {
        IncrementRef();
    }

    template<typename T2>
    Ref(const Ref<T2>& other) noexcept
    {
        data = (T*)other.data;
        IncrementRef();
    }

    template<typename T2>
    Ref(Ref<T2>&& other) noexcept
    {
        data = (T*)other.data;
        other.data = nullptr;
    }

    ~Ref() noexcept
    {
        DecrementRef();
    }

    Ref(const Ref<T>& other) noexcept
        : data(other.data)
    {
        IncrementRef();
    }

    [[nodiscard]] inline Ref& operator=(std::nullptr_t) noexcept
    {
        DecrementRef();
        data = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] inline Ref& operator=(const Ref<T>& other) noexcept
    {
        other.IncrementRef();
        DecrementRef();

        data = other.data;
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T2>
    [[nodiscard]] inline Ref& operator=(const Ref<T2>& other) noexcept
    {
        other.IncrementRef();
        DecrementRef();

        data = other.data;
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T2>
    [[nodiscard]] inline Ref& operator=(Ref<T2>&& other) noexcept
    {
        DecrementRef();

        data = other.data;
        other.data = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] inline operator bool() noexcept { return data != nullptr; }
    [[nodiscard]] inline operator bool() const noexcept { return data != nullptr; }

    [[nodiscard]] inline bool operator==(const Ref<T>& other) const noexcept
    {
        return data == other.data;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] inline bool operator!=(const Ref<T>& other) const noexcept
    {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

    [[nodiscard]] inline T* operator->() noexcept { return data; }
    [[nodiscard]] inline const T* operator->() const noexcept { return data; }

    [[nodiscard]] inline T& operator*() noexcept { return *data; }
    [[nodiscard]] inline const T& operator*() const noexcept { return *data; }

    [[nodiscard]] inline T* get() noexcept { return data; }
    [[nodiscard]] inline const T* get() const noexcept { return data; }

    inline void Reset(T* instance = nullptr) noexcept
    {
        DecrementRef();
        data = instance;
    }

    template<typename T2>
    [[nodiscard]] inline Ref<T2> as() const noexcept
    {
        return Ref<T2>(*this);
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    [[nodiscard]] inline static Ref<T> Create(Args&&... args) noexcept
    {
        return Ref<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

private:
    inline void IncrementRef() const noexcept
    {
        if (data) {
            data->IncrementRefCount();
        }
    }

    inline void DecrementRef() const noexcept
    {
        if (data) {
            data->DecrementRefCount();
            if (data->getRefCount() == 0) {
                delete data;
            }
        }
    }

    template<typename T2>
    friend struct Ref;

    T* data = nullptr;
};

template<typename T>
class WeakRef
{
public:
    WeakRef() noexcept = default;

    WeakRef(Ref<T> ref) noexcept
    {
        data = ref.get();
    }

    WeakRef(T* instance) noexcept
        : data(instance)
    {
    }

    [[nodiscard]] inline Ref<T> lock() const noexcept { return Ref<T>(data); }

    [[nodiscard]] inline bool isValid() const noexcept { return data; }
    [[nodiscard]] inline operator bool() const noexcept { return isValid(); }

private:
    T* data = nullptr;
};
```

```cpp
struct Leaf;
struct Node : RefCount
{
    virtual ~Node() noexcept = default;

    void PrintLeafName() noexcept const;

    Ref<Leaf> leaf = nullptr;
    std::string name;

protected:
    Node(const std::string_view name) noexcept
        : name(name)
    {
    }
};

struct ConcreteNode : Node
{
    ConcreteNode(const std::string_view name, const std::string_view leafName) noexcept;
    ~ConcreteNode() noexcept override = default;
};

struct Leaf : RefCount
{
    virtual ~Leaf() noexcept = default;

    virtual void PrintName() const noexcept = 0;
    void PrintNodeName() const noexcept
    {
        std::cout << parent.lock()->name << "\n";
    }

protected:
    Leaf(WeakRef<Node> parent, const std::string_view name) noexcept 
        : parent(std::move(parent)), name(name)
    {
    }

    WeakRef<Node> parent;
    std::string name;
};

struct ConcreteLeaf : Leaf
{
    ConcreteLeaf(WeakRef<Node> parent, const std::string_view name) noexcept 
        : Leaf(std::move(parent), name)
    {
    }
    ~ConcreteLeaf() noexcept override = default;

    void PrintName() const noexcept
    {
        std::cout << name <<"\n";
    }
};

ConcreteNode::ConcreteNode(std::string_view name, std::string_view leafName) noexcept
    : Node(name)
{
    leaf = Ref<ConcreteLeaf>::Create(this, leafName);
}

void Node::PrintLeafName() const noexcept
{
    leaf->PrintName();
}

int main()
{
    Ref<Node> node = Ref<ConcreteNode>::Create("Concrete node", "Concrete leaf");

    node->PrintLeafName();
    node->leaf->PrintNodeName();

    return 0;
}
```

Could you review it please? I'm not sure if `RefCount` class needs a virtual destructor. `Ref` class deletes `T`, so I don't think it's needed, but I may be wrong.

I'm also not sure of `mutable std::atomic_uint32_t refCount`, but it's required for `RefCount::as() const`

https://godbolt.org/z/cvGzaqvqe

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bugs: `WeakRef` is a big fat bug. Say you have your smart pointer `Ref`, create one `WeakRef` from it. Then clear `Ref`. Then use `lock()` function on `WeakRef`... voila a UB as you address deleted memory.

`std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` implement the whole thing by keeping control block separately. Once all `shared_ptr` are gone the object is deleted. And only once all `weak_ptr` are gone too, the control block is deleted too.
Not sure how you should implement it but the managed object needs to be destroyed once all references are gone while the mechanism behind weak references needs to be kept alive as long as some weak references still exist. Do you really need weak references with intrusive smart pointers? For me it feels that the two don't mesh well together.

The `acquire_release` memory order in `DecrementRefCount()` is overkill. You need only to call `release` regularly. While apply `acquire` fence only prior to destroying the object. Also the routine, `DecrementRef()` in `Ref` is buggy. You first decrease the value then read it. What if it is decreased simultaneously in two places and then it is read simultaneously in two places? You'll get double-delete. `DecrementRefCount()` should return the value given by `fetch_sub` and use it to judge whether to delete or not.

Assignment operators: make sure operation like self-assignment (`x = x;` and `x = std::move(x);`) are safe. Currently they might behave weirdly or do unnecessary operations. While it doesn't normally happen people might accidentally trigger it in complicated calls.

Operators like `->`, `*`, and `get()` ought to be const and return the object without unnecessary const. Here constness means that the pointer is unchanged but the data is under users' responsibility not the smart pointer's. It is probably overkill for your homework assignment but the class should support `T` being a `const` object. `std::shared_ptr<const double>` is a thing.

**Clarification:** Say you have a function `foo(const Ref<A>& a)`. And `bar()` is not a const function of `A`. Then writing `a->bar()` is a compilation error because `->` returns a const pointer. However, one can write `Ref<A> a2 = a;` and then call `a2->bar();` which is absurd, right? So returning a const pointer via `->` is illogical. The situation with `*` and `get()` is the same.

`RefCount`'s operations should be only accessible to `Ref` and `WeakRef`.

Writing `const std::string_view` in function calls is superfluous. Write simply `std::string_view`.

The class is inconvenient to use. `Ref<int>` and `Ref<std::string>` will not compile. It should be able to figure out on its own if the object does not have the control block mechanism and add it automatically while wrapping and unwrapping all the calls for the user's convenience.

The class does not work with polymorphism. It is frequent that one first declares an `Interface` and then creates a `Derived` class. Normally users want to hold smart pointer to `Interface`, right? With this implementation it is impossible.

You shouldn't put `noexcept` everywhere. There are places where it is much more reasonable to not have it. They are only important for move constructor and move assignment else STL algorithm won't work right with the classes.

---

1. Regarding your questions:

Self-Assignment:

```
Ref<A> x;
x = x;
x = std::move(x);
```

Well, nobody would ever write that, right? But imagine situation:

```
bool DoStuff(Ref<A>& input, Ref<A>& output)
{
     // lots of convoluted and branched code, some with early returns.
     output = std::move(input);
     return true;
}
```

And then someone decided to use it with `DoStuff(x,x)` for whatever reason. That'll cause a bug if self-assignment were not safe. That's being said, some STL classes do weird stuff on self-move-assignment, like `std::vector` that clears itself.

2. The class does not work with polymorphism: Okey I didn't check it fully and just saw that you didn't implement any proper mechanisms.

First, your

```
template<typename T2>
Ref(const Ref<T2>& other) noexcept
{
    data = (T*)other.data;
    IncrementRef();
}
```

Is extremely unsafe. With explicit pointer cast you can cast completely unrelated classes. For implicit conversion you ought to require `T` is a base of `T2`. When it is not the case, you ought to write external functions that perform dynamic casting and static casting. Like `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` and `std::static_pointer_cast` do for `std::shared_ptr`. Otherwise, you can easily cast cats into bananas.

Also, as it is now, it is also buggy. Calling delete on pointer to an interface will cause UB. That's because the destructor is not virtual. `RefCounter` should declare its destructor virtual.

Comment: If `std::make_shared()` and the like are used, the control-block is *not* separate in better implementations. Destroying the object (without freeing it, as coalesced allocation) and destroying the control-block (including freeing it, and any coalesced allocation) are still cleanly separated though.

Comment: @Deduplicator it is not separate per C++ standart. But it doesn't follow intrusive smart pointer logic and requires each smart pointer instance to have two pointers, to the data and to the control block.

Comment: OP has asked you some questions in their answer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/282227/52915). The answer will eventually be taken down, but feel free to discuss further here in the comments.

Comment: So to avoid Self-Assignment  I should do `if(&other == this) { return; }`?

Comment: @Edziju yeah, only that `return *this;` instead of plain `return;`. For shared pointers you can compare pointers to avoid unnecessary increment+decrement when the pointers manage the same object, not essential by any means.

Comment: What if `WeakRef::Lock()` would check if `T*` is inside a `static std::unordered_set<void*> validReferences` and if it's not it will return a nullptr? Is it a good idea?

Comment: @Edziju It can work. But you'd need to make it thread safe and have the smart pointer instances add/remove the elements into the set on construction/destruction. You'd better write a singleton that manages this rather than have a free-to-use static set. Also, it better be a set of `RefCounter*` rather than `void*`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I've thought about. To have a `RefHelper` class that has `void Add(RefCounter* data)`, `void Remove(RefCounter* data)`, `bool isValid(RefCounter* data)` and `static RefHelper& get()` and `std::unordered_set<void*> validInstances` and `std::mutex mutex`. Or just static functions and members instead of `static RefHelper& get()`

Comment: @Edziju `isValid` is useless. It can return true, but by the time you construct `Ref` from the pointer it can be deleted by another thread. You'd better have `TryGet` or something.

Comment: Even though it'll lock the mutex first?

Comment: @Edziju and `Remove` is not good either, it should be `TryRemove` where reference counter is checked again.

Comment: @Edziju you want to place mutex outside of the class?

Comment: Something like this https://godbolt.org/z/r6xfbWhWW

Comment: @Edziju yes, that's the unsafe way to code it.

Comment: Would it be safe to check if data is not nullptr and if it's not do a CAS loop on a refcount to check if it's 0? Or even `if (data)` and `if(!data)` is not safe?

Comment: @Edziju I am not sure what you refer to. You'd better write a fix to the issues and post newer version for review. Also stackoverflow is a better place to ask questions on memory safety.

Comment: Alright, cool. Thank you

Comment: @ALX23z Unless you have a very skewed sample, optimizing for self-assignment is counter-productive. Just write it so the normal path does the right thing anyway.